# how to hide the left menu on tap anywhere on android screen xamarin forms?

Tags: android, menu, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms. I am using Master detail page to open left menu. And its working fine. Right now menu hide only when user click on menu icon on top. But I want if menu is open, then if user click anywhere on screen, menu should hide.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do it using a custom renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BaseMasterDetailPage), typeof(MyMasterDetailPageRenderer))]

namespace Driver.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class MyMasterDetailPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {
        public override bool OnTouchEvent(Android.Views.MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Up)
                new Task(CloseDrawers).Start(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. But I don't understand why we still need a custom renderer to do basic expected behavior.

Comment: Have you raised this enhancement request as an issue on the Xamarin Forms GitHub repo?